# css float left two elements

Tags: html, css

I wish to have the span tag float left and have the `<section>` floated left beside it also. But the `<section>` sits below the span.

I would imagine it has something to do with setting the widths of the elements but I want it to be responsive and flex.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3 class="highlight-sub"><em>Start using your card today</em></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <span class="step">1</span>
               <section>
                    <h4 class="highlight-prim">Complete Form</h4>
                    <p class="highlight-sub">Simply fill in our online form and your account will created.</p>
               </section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="step">2</span>
                <section>
                    <h4 class="highlight-prim">Receive by Post</h4>
                    <p class="highlight-sub">You will be sent your new card in post.</p>
                </section>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="step">3</span>
                <section>
                    <h4 class="highlight-prim">Start Enjoying</h4>
                    <p class="highlight-sub">Present your new card to any of our partners for al the benifits.</p>
                </section>      
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>

#mid-content span.step {
  border: 2px solid #A99269;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #A99269;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em;
  font-size: 32px;
  float: left
}

#mid-content section {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float to the left ***only*** the `.step` element, and give to the `section` a left margin equal to the total width of the `.step` (*with total i mean including borders..*)

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/sqD6Q/
(*with arbitrary margin since i do not know your currest styles to calculate the margin..*)

Comment: Thanks for the help, really didnt know to set the margin. I had tried the others ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably the content of the `section` is almost 100% of the row, and it goes to the second row. You can place the span inside the section

Comment: If I put the span inside the section I get the heading and paragraph tag wrapped around it.